# Growing trees.. Progress: 1%. Estimated remaining time: 1 hour, 4 minutes, 21 seconds

Tags: r, random-forest

When I run a random forrest using "ranger" with caret package, I receive output like the following while running:

> Growing trees.. Progress: 1%. Estimated remaining time: 1 hour, 4
>   minutes, 21 seconds. Growing trees.. Progress: 2%. Estimated remaining
>   time: 1 hour, 3 minutes, 43 seconds. Growing trees.. Progress: 4%.
>   Estimated remaining time: 51 minutes, 28 seconds. Growing trees..
>   Progress: 5%. Estimated remaining time: 45 minutes, 32 seconds.
>   Growing trees.. Progress: 7%. Estimated remaining time: 39 minutes, 12
>   seconds.

Once it gets to 100% it starts again. It's been running a few hours already and is already on it's 5th iteration.

Looking at documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ranger/versions/0.6.0/topics/ranger) it looks like num.trees defaults to 500?

I just want to sanity check I have understood this correctly. If I leave my computer running will it try to do this 500 times? Or have I misunderstood the output?

Comment: How many predictors are in your model, and also how many observations are you using to train the forest?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen there are ~350 variables and ~30k observations

Comment: I am not famiiar with `caret`, only `randomForest`.  One hour sounds reasonable given your data set, 500 hours does not.

Comment: Actually I'm running 5 fold cross validation (I should have thought off and mentioned that in my question). I'm wondering if the console output is referring to a fold (where 1 through 100% is per fold) or if it's referring to a single tree. Hopefully a fold! Then at least it's nearly done

Comment: Random forests don't need cross validation, the validation happens implicitly as the forest is being built.

Comment: Oh. I was not aware of that, thanks for sharing. Is this a widely known fact or do many people still do CV with rf?

Comment: Of course the model must be measured against real, untrained data, but this happens during the building process.

Comment: I'll do some research, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I found this SO post which, if I follow, suggests that if comparing RF to other algorythms then use CV, else if comparing several RF models to each other no CV needed. Does that sound like a good rule of thumb? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608721/is-it-neccessary-to-run-random-forest-with-cross-validation-at-the-same-time

Comment: My limited understanding is that the out-of-bag process used to build each tree in the forest simulates the behavior of cross validation.  I used RF for many years and I _never_ used CV.  Maybe there is something kinky with the `caret` package but I doubt this.